How to make the spacing between these circles consistent?
I want to draw the  stacked (or generalized) prism graph nicely.
g = PlanarGraph[
  GraphProduct[CycleGraph[8], PathGraph[{1, 2, 3, 4}], "Cartesian"], 
  VertexLabels -> None]

The Mathematica gives me the following:

Currently, I am not very satisfied with two things: first, the spacing between the circles, from the inner to the outer ones, is inconsistent; second, I would like it to be more aesthetically pleasing. I hope one of the edges aligns with the horizontal line, like in the example below (from Stacked Prism Graph).


It seems that the built-in GraphData[{"StackedPrism", {8, 4}}] meets my requirements. However, I still want to learn how to handle this programmatically.

Just a comment on the title of the question. I think the plot is consistent in the sense that the 3D cylinder is viewed in perspective. You might use "not equally spaced". (^_^)

Edit

Directly construct the graph.
To build the cycles,we using Partition[#, 2, 1, 1],and to buid the radial lines,we using Partition[#, 2, 1].

Clear[ptss];
n = 8;
k = 4;
c = 1/(k + 1);
ptss = Table[CirclePoints[1 - c*k, n], {k, 1, k}];
Graph[{UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ ptss, 
   UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Transpose@ptss} // 
  Flatten, VertexCoordinates -> Flatten[ptss, 1]]



A starting point.

n = 8;
k = 4;
c = 1/(k + 1);
ptss = Table[
   Append[#, First@#] &@CirclePoints[{1 - c*k, 0}, n], {k, 1, k}];
g = Graphics[{Line /@ ptss, 
     Line /@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ Transpose@ptss}] // 
   DiscretizeGraphics // MeshConnectivityGraph



The code is cute.

By: ptss = Map[{{Cos[Pi/8], Sin[Pi/8]}, {-Sin[Pi/8], Cos[Pi/8]}} . # &,     ptss, {2}]; you can turn the graph so that some lines are parallel to the x axis.

@DanielHuber  I deliberately set  CirclePoints[{1 - c*k, 0}, n] instead of CirclePoints[1 - c*k, n] according to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StackedPrismGraph.html

@cvgmt valuable update. Always find it helpful to see variants. Had already +1 :)

@ubpdqn  Thansks again :-)

Another variation:
stackedPrismGraph[{n_, m_}, opts___] :=
    Block[{coord, g},
        coord = Flatten[Table[CirclePoints[r/m, n], {r, m}], 1];
        g = GraphProduct[CycleGraph[n],PathGraph[Range[m]],"Cartesian"];
        Graph[g, VertexCoordinates -> coord, opts]
    ]

stackedPrismGraph[#, VertexStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[Red], Red], 
   EdgeStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> {.03, .03}] & /@ {{8, 3}, {8, 
   2}, {5, 5}}



neat , maintaining GraphProduct and specifying coordinates upfront +1:)
